# copy-construct child into parent type pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have a parent class with multiple children

```
namespace var
{
enum type {t_int, t_float, t_string, t_null};

class root
    {
    public:
        type t = t_null;
        root(type t) : t(t) {}
    }

class v_int : public root
    {
    public:
        int value;
        v_int() : root(t_int) {}
        v_int(int value) : value(value), root(t_int) {}
    }
class v_float : public root
    {
    public:
        float value;
        v_float() : root(t_float) {}
        v_float(float value) : value(value), root(t_float) {}
    }
class v_string : public root
    {
    public:
        std::string value;
        v_string() : root(t_string) {}
        v_string(std::string value) : value(value), root(t_string) {}
    }
}
```

and a function that needs to create a copy a child in a `root*`, but the child comes already as a root*, and i whish to avoid a switch to find the type, call the specific constructor, and assign it to root*, since it'd be identical for all children.

```
var::root* source = new var::v_int(5);
var::root* copy = /*copy of source*/;
```

---

Yes i know, raw pointers, how do i dare!!! I'm not here to discuss pointer type choices anyway.

---

I know i could do something similar with a single class and an union, but this class will be used a lot and i don't want the future "v_uint8_t" to take as much space as a "v_int64_t"

Comment: Use a `virtual` `clone()` function implemented for each _type_.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ there's no built-in way to achieve the same result?

Comment: No, there isn't a built in way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, are you asking for a way to copy the element without having to switch over the potential subclasses ?

If that's the case, simply add a pure virtual member function to your `root` class :

```
class root{
  // [...]
  public:
    virtual root* clone() const = 0;
  // [...]
};
```

And implement it in the subclasses :

```
class v_int : public root{
  // [...]
  public:
    root* clone() const override{
      return new v_int{this->value};
    }
  // [...]
};
```

Aside from this, in your example you do not show any inheritance (except a constructor call).

Comment: I thought there could be a native way but i'll take the virtual function route, thanks!
just corrected the example thanks for pointing out

Comment: may i ask why you're using the curly braces constructor instead of the normal one?

Comment: It's part of the uniform initializer syntax, it's removes any ambiguity (w/ call operator for instance).